# XMLNS attribute removed by Slow Cheetah transformation

Tags: xslt, slowcheetah

I'm trying to use Slow Cheetah to transform a Windows scheduled task config file.  I'm simply trying to add "repetition" node information, like so:

**ORIGINAL:**

```
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2013-01-02T09:32:12.2196371</Date>
    <Author>xxx</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-01-10T01:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
.....
</Task>
```

**REQUIRED, ADDITIONAL XML**

```
<CalendarTrigger>
   <Repetition>
     <Interval>PT300S</Interval>
   </Repetition>
</CalendarTrigger>
```

To do this, I have the following transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<Task version="1.2">
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT300S</Interval>
      </Repetition>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
</Task>
```

The problem I'm having is that all attributes outside of the CalendarTrigger node are removed (and therefore making the resultant transformation config an invalid scheduled task format).

I have tried adding

```
xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"
```

to the Task node, but the attribute is then generated at CalendarTrigger level (and I cannot put this attribute on the original, because I then get "No element in the source document matches '/Task/Triggers' ").

Any pointers?

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be isolated to the **xmlns** attribute; if I try to include this in the 'Task' node of the original, I get "No element in the source document matches '/Task/Triggers'" - BUT changing this attribute to 'xmlns2' works fine and produces exactly what I need (albeit with an 'xmlns2' attribute!).  Is this a known limitation of Slow Cheetah?  Anyone know of a potential work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `xdt:Transform="Insert"` is one level to high.

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<Task xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <Triggers>
      <CalendarTrigger>
        <Repetition xdt:Transform="Insert">
          <Interval>PT300S</Interval>
        </Repetition>
      </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
</Task>
```

Comment: Thanks - you are correct about my transform attribute being applied at the wrong level, but I'm still left with the original problem - attributes outside of the xdt:Transform are removed (which breaks the scheduled task format, since it requires 'xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"' in the root 'Task' node...

Comment: @NickH I have tried with the example you provided and it works with my edited answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I'm still unable to get this to work correctly.  The resultant transformation is perfect - apart from the missing xmlns attribute in the Task header node.  Perhaps this is due to an older version of Slow Cheetah?  I will investigate and update accordingly...

Comment: A colleague has been able to successfully produce the desired transformation (using both VS and msbuild), with the exact same code base, so it just seems to be a problem on my local machine.  Accepting your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using the 2.5.3 version if it can help.